# Obtener los valores del input

Tags: validación, checkbox, sweetalert2, sumatoria

Buen día, espero que alguien me pueda dar una idea de como resolver este detalle,  estuve investigando ya varios días en diversas paginas para llegar al siguiente código:

```js
    
       
function valida_pagos(obj){
            
            var fecha_inicia = $("#fecha_inicia").val();// todavía no la utilizo
            
            //var pago_referencia="";
             //var pagos = [];
             var suma_pagos="";
             
   if ($('#forma_pago_1')[0].checked==true) {
                    
        var  pago_referencia = $("#cantidad_rb_1").val();
    
            }else{
                
                 var  pago_referencia = 0;         
        }
            
    if ($('#forma_pago_2')[0].checked==true) {
                    
           var pago_efectivo = $("#cantidad_pe_1").val();
                    
            }else{
                
                var  pago_efectivo = 0;         
        }

    if ($('#forma_pago_3')[0].checked==true) {
                
            var pago_tranferencia_bancaria = $("#cantidad_tb_1").val();
                    
            }else{
                
                 var  pago_tranferencia_bancaria = 0;         
        }
        
    if ($('#forma_pago_4')[0].checked==true) {
                 
             if ($('#distribucion_ptb_1')[0].checked == true) {
                 
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_1 = $("#cantidad_ptb_1").val();
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_2 = 0; 
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_3 = 0;
             }  //Hasta aqui pago 1 terminal
             
             if ($('#distribucion_ptb_2')[0].checked==true) {
                 
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_1 = $("#cantidad_ptb_1").val();
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_2 = $("#cantidad_ptb_2").val();
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_3 = 0;
              } 
           
            if ($('#distribucion_ptb_3')[0].checked==true) {
                 
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_1 = $("#cantidad_ptb_1").val();
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_2 = $("#cantidad_ptb_2").val();
                    var pago_terminal_bancaria_3 = $("#cantidad_ptb_3").val();  
            }
             
        }
            
        
        var pago_total = $("#monto_total").val();
            
            
                pago_referencia=(pago_referencia=='')?0:parseFloat(pago_referencia);
                pago_efectivo=(pago_efectivo=='')?0:parseFloat(pago_efectivo);
                pago_terminal_bancaria_1=(pago_terminal_bancaria_1 =='')?0:parseFloat(pago_terminal_bancaria_1 );
                pago_terminal_bancaria_2=(pago_terminal_bancaria_2 =='')?0:parseFloat(pago_terminal_bancaria_2 );
                pago_terminal_bancaria_3=(pago_terminal_bancaria_3 =='')?0:parseFloat(pago_terminal_bancaria_3 );
                pago_tranferencia_bancaria=(pago_tranferencia_bancaria=='')?0:parseFloat(pago_tranferencia_bancaria);
                
                
              
            //suma_pagos = pago_referencia + pago_efectivo + pago_terminal_bancaria_1 + pago_terminal_bancaria_2 + pago_terminal_bancaria_3 + pago_tranferencia_bancaria;
            suma_pagos = pago_referencia + pago_efectivo + pago_tranferencia_bancaria + pago_terminal_bancaria_1 + pago_terminal_bancaria_2 + pago_terminal_bancaria_3;
            suma_pagos.toFixed(2);
               
              Swal.fire({ 
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Monto a pagar...' ,
                        text: suma_pagos ,//
                        //footer: 'Pago con Referencia Bancaria',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        confirmButtonText: 'ACEPTAR'      
              }); // final del swal //
           
 }
```

Una vez que se ha seleccionado un checkbox y habilita el fieldset, pulsando un botón que  llama a la función "valida_pagos", este código checa cual de los 4 checkbox ha sido marcado o seleccionado, y a través de una variable declarada y uso de .val();  recupero el valor del costo que tiene un servicio determinado, aquí el detalle es que para las tres primeras formas de pago: "#forma_pago_1","#forma_pago_2" y "#forma_pago_3", de manera aislada es decir si no existe el código correspondiente a la "#forma_pago_4", si me muestra en la ventana la sumatoria correcta del monto señalado, o la sumatoria de los tres montos ingresados para cada tipo de forma de pago.  El problema es cuando se integra el código que corresponde ala "#forma_pago_4", en ese momento deja de mostrarme la sumatoria de las tres primeros,  excepto si primero elijo la forma "#forma_pago_4" y luego voy marcando las otras, pero si desmarco la forma "#forma_pago_4" deja de mostrar el resultado de las tres primeros cada que se pulsa el botón para cualquier combinación que se haga de las tres primeras formas de pago.

En la sección que corresponde a la forma de pago "#forma_pago_4" se utilizan radio button para dividir el costo en dos o tres partes. y bueno ya probada esta funcionalidad sin problema la ventana me muestra ya sea el monto original, o a dos pagos, o a tres pagos dividendo dicha cantidad. Ya probé también de varias formas este código, se ha modificado varias veces, y se depuro  y al final lo que se esta compartiendo es lo que me ha funcionado sin problema para dividir un pago en dos o tres partes , posteriormente con el código de "#forma_pago_4" y donde se suman los valores obtenidos la suma da correctamente y se muestra sin problema en la ventana emergente de sweetalert2

Seguiré buscando como puedo resolver este detalle, pero si a alguien se le ocurre alguna idea, o si me equivoque de alguna manera les agradezco sus observación o recomendación para
resolver este inconveniente.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Cesarin, debes colocar un ejemplo funcional del asunto incluido el HTML, además te recuerdo que en el snnipet al lado izquierdo puedes incluir jquery. Además te recomiendo ser más conciso con el problema, a mí no me ha quedado del todo claro.

Comment: @Yussef agradezco el comentario.  Buen dia

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le interesa la solución a este tema:

Quizás no sea lo mas prolijo pero funciono , la verdad no encontré cual es el problema quizás sea los nombres largos, así que termine asignando los valores
de las variables a otras con nombres mas pequeños siendo así que quedaron de esta forma:

```
n1 = document.getElementById('cantidad_ptb_1').value;
.
.
.
.
.

n6 = document.getElementById('cantidad_xxx_n').value;

n1=(n1=='')?0:parseFloat(n1);
n2=(n2=='')?0:parseFloat(n2);
n3=(n3=='')?0:parseFloat(n3);
n4=(n4=='')?0:parseFloat(n4);
n5=(n5=='')?0:parseFloat(n5);
n6=(n6=='')?0:parseFloat(n6);
```

y las operaciones como suma y resta funcionaron de manera adecuada.

```
suma_pagos = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 +n5 +n6;
suma_pagos.toFixed(2);
```

De esta manera ya permite mostrar los montos correctos en el Swal.

Saludos